# Try to safe an object to the localStorage with ngxs

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, ngxs

I'm trying to save a state object in the localStorage of the browser by using the 'ngxs/storage-plugin' plugin version 3.5.1. The reason for using ngxs is that we use ngxs for all other states in combination with an http-client to save the state in the backend.

I searched for an example in the web because the doc of ngxs is really poor at this point but the result is poor as well.

Here my code which I already wrote. The state was working well but after I started to add the local storage plugin I was lost.

settings.actions.ts

```
export class SetShowHelp {
  static readonly type = '[MySettings] Set my configuration for the flag showHelp';
  constructor(public showHelp: boolean) {}
}
```

settings.state.ts

```
import { State, Action, StateContext, Selector } from '@ngxs/store';

import {
  SetShowHelp
} from '../actions/mysettings.actions';


export class SettingsStateModel {
  public showHelp: boolean;
  public hideToolbar: boolean
}

@State<SettingsStateModel>({
  name: 'my-settings',
  defaults: {
    showHelp: true,
    hideToolbar: false
  }
})

export class SettingsState {

  @Selector()
  static getShowHelp(state: SettingsStateModel) {
    return state.showHelp;
  }

  constructor() { }


  @Action(SetShowHelp)
  setShowHelp({ patchState }: StateContext<SettingsStateModel>, {showHelp}: SetShowHelp) {
    // patch the state and write into local storage
    patchState({
      showHelp: showHilfe
    });
  }

  .....

}
```

app.module.ts

```
  NgxsModule.forRoot(),
  NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({
      key: SettingsState
    }),
```

How to write the 'SettingsStateModel' object into the localStorage?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the name of my state includes a minus which is not allowed. I changed the name to 'mysettings'. I also changed the `app.module.ts` to:

```
  NgxsModule.forRoot([SettingsState]),
  NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({
    key: 'mysettings'
  }),
```

After all changes everything works fine.